# SSRS-Best way to represent specific metrics

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I'm self-training in SSRS 2014. I have a specific set of data I'd like to represent, to wit: we have a fund-raising goal, and have money coming in toward that goal. The money coming in falls into one of four different buckets - so I'm looking for something stacked-but-horizontal (one bar) that shows the bucketed totals, and then some "blank" space representing what we need to reach our goal. I've tried a linear gauge (couldn't figure out how to get the "bucketed" portions to show, even with the data group); a data bar (couldn't get the labels to display correctly because they must be displayed inside the bar); other representations cause multiple bars, which I don't want.

I've been researching and trying things for two days...I'm wondering if this thing that seems so simple is in fact not particularly do-able in SSRS, or if I've just chosen poor methods. What IS the best way to represent these data? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your best bet is a simple bar graph. In my opinion, the key here is to have the value of the bar be represented by the percent of the goal collected. However, you want the label for each bar to be the actual amount of money collected thus far. This way, your bar grows proportionally as it approaches the goal, but the label shows the amount collected.

Alternatively, you could create a tablix containing the percent completed as a databar and show the amount collected thus far versus the goal.

Included is a screenshot of the samples. Please note the following:

1. I hard-coded the names of the colors in the query. This is a great way to control how your charts look and feel. Then you simply change the color to represent an expression equal to the color field's value. For varying light and dark colors, you can also set the font color, so if you have a light blue bar you can have a black text instead of white or vice versa.
2. When using labels on bar graphs, you need to code in a bare-minimum value for the bar. This will ensure that when you have something like Bucket 5 where you're at 5% of the goal (a relatively small bar) but the amount is large ($124,243), that the bar will adjust to be big enough to contain the label. In this case, if the percent collected is less than 15%, then the bar size will be 15%.

   [image: Examples]

If you have any questions, leave a comment and I'll do my best to help. The query I used to generate the dataset is below.

```
With CTE as (
Select 'Bucket 1' as bucket, 'blue' as color, 'white' as text_color, 50 as percent_total, 15236 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 2' as bucket, 'red' as color, 'white' as text_color, 33 as percent_total, 24685 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 3' as bucket, 'green' as color, 'black' as text_color, 67 as percent_total, 41457 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 4' as bucket, 'purple' as color, 'white' as text_color, 95 as percent_total, 32493 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 5' as bucket, 'black' as color, 'white' as text_color, 5 as percent_total, 124243 as amount
)

Select CTE.*
    , CAST(amount as float) / (CAST(percent_total as float) / 100.00) as Goal

From CTE

Order by Bucket desc
```

**Edited based on Comments**

If you want all buckets with the remainder on a single bar, then you can accomplish that with the following (although I'm not sure how you would handle labeling the amounts to the individual buckets).

*The End Result*

[image]

*The Query*

```
Declare @Goal int = 500000;

With CTE as (
Select 'Bucket 5' as bucket, 'blue' as color, 'white' as text_color,  15236 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 4' as bucket, 'red' as color, 'white' as text_color, 24685 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 2' as bucket, 'green' as color, 'black' as text_color,  41457 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 3' as bucket, 'purple' as color, 'white' as text_color,  32493 as amount Union all
Select 'Bucket 1' as bucket, 'black' as color, 'white' as text_color, 124243 as amount
)

Select CTE.bucket
    , CTE.color
    , CTE.text_color
    , CTE.amount
    , CAST(CTE.amount as float) / CAST(@Goal as float) as percent_total
    , 'white' as border_color

From CTE

Union All

Select 'Remaining' as bucket
    , 'Transparent' as color
    , 'Transparent' as text_color
    , @Goal - SUM(CTE.amount) as amount
    , CAST(@Goal - SUM(CTE.amount) as float) / CAST(@Goal as float) as percent_total
    , 'black' as border_color

From CTE

Order by Bucket
```

*The Setup in Report Builder*

Note that I've dynamically changed the border color to be:

```
=Fields!border_color.value
```

and the color of the bar to be:

```
=Fields!color.value
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I realized I was not clear enough in my question - I need ONE bar to show the buckets, then blank space until the goal total. Those are lovely examples, btw...now if I could just connect all the bars together and label them nicely outside the viz, I'd be all set! :)

Comment: Do you need to show labels for each bucket's contribution to the total?

Comment: I do. I realized I could probably make very short labels, like A, B, C, etc., and then have a line of text outside the actual chart that shows what those things mean.

Comment: Holy cats, I just looked up at what you did - wow, perfect! Thank you so much! I'm going to give this a shot and see how I do, and what I can learn from this. Very generous.

Comment: It's no problem. Those of us that answer on here do so for reputation points. If you find an answer helpful, give that answer an upvote. When you pose a question, choose the most helpful and correct answer as the correct one. This ensures everyone gets the appropriate credit for their work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the table wizard. IF you click on the table wizard you can choose which fields to chow and if you want to group on which "Bucket" it falls under. Just drag and drop your values into the values box and your buckets into the row group box and then follow the wizard and it should create it all for you.

Comment: I have not tried this - I'll give it a whirl, thank you.